# React state variable changes when calculating on it (without setting it)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a `useState` hook in a functional component to store data. I want to display the data in another unit however. Therefore I do a calculation on the data before feeding it to my component. It looks like that calculation is saved in the state variable however, and since react rerenders the component every now and then, the data gets divided by 1000 multiple times. As far as I see, I am not calling the setState function (`setPriceData`) after initial assignment, nor do I alter the state variable (`priceData`) itself.

My Minimal Reproducible Example:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import MyComponent from "MyComponent"

const PriceGraph = () => {
  const [priceData, setPriceData] = useState<Array<{ x: Date, y: number }>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [
      {
        x: new Date("2023-04-04T13:00:00"),
        y: 108.71
      },
      {
        x: new Date("2023-04-04T14:00:00"),
        y: 112.73
      }
    ]
    setPriceData(data)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent data={getChartData(priceData)} />
      <span>
        {priceData[0]?.y}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

function getChartData(data: Array<{ x: Date, y: number }>) {
  return {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: mwhToKwh(data),
      },
    ],
  }
}

function mwhToKwh(data: Array<{ x: Date, y: number }>) {
  return data.map(point => {
    point.y /= 1000
    return point
  })
}

export default PriceGraph
```

The expected result is that the data in the span stays the same over time when React rerenders and recalculates the conversion on the original data (`priceData`). The actual result however is that the printed data is getting smaller by a factor 1000 on every rerender. How is this possible? Am I missing a React lifecycle or hook behaviour?

Comment: "looks like that calculation is saved in the state variable however" correct.  `point.y /= 1000` changes the object that it receives

Answer (score 0):

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas) correctly points out, I am referencing `point.y` and setting it to itself divided by 1000. Since this is a reference variable and not a (deep) clone, the state variable is altered.

Solution: deep cloning or, since it's suck a simple object:

```js
function mwhToKwh(data: Array<{ x: Date, y: number }>) {
  return data.map(point => {
    return {x: point.x, y: point.y / 1000}
  })
}
```